# PHP SimpleXML - don't collapse empty tags

Tags: php, xml, dom, simplexml

Is there any way to prevent SimpleXML from collapsing empty tags?

For example, if you input

```
<foo></foo>
```

Then write the output, it has become:

```
<foo />
```

What I really want, is for tags that have been defined as closed to be closed but not ones that haven't.

E.g.

an input of

```
<foo />
<bar></bar>
```

Is output as that, not as :

```
<foo />
<bar />
```

or

```
<foo></foo>
<bar></bar>
```

Is that possible?

Comment: Why do you require this?

Comment: A syntax of `<foo></foo>` is exactly the same as `<foo />` so I am wondering why you would need to distinguish this. If there is a reason, it might be better to challenge the cause of this requirement.

Comment: I'm loading some XHTML. Some of which contains tags like this: <script src="..."></script> and <img src="..." />. As it collapses the script to become <script src="..." /> after it's been parsed and output it isn't correctly interpreted by browsers.

Comment: @TomB than stop mixing XML and HTML

Comment: Perhaps using `loadHTML` instead. But I fail to understand why you want the server to load a XHTML file in the first place to do processing. Why not write a PHP script to generate the XHTML in the first place.

Comment: The whole point of XHTML is that it's designed to be parsed using XML parsers. From the w3 spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#xhtml "XHTML documents are XML conforming. As such, they are readily viewed, edited, and validated with standard XML tools."

Comment: Try fudging it so that `<script>` contains a whitespace child element which should result in `<script src="..."> </script>`

Comment: @TomB - Be that as it may the fact of the matter is that some browsers do not conform. Also are you telling the browser (i am guessing here that you pass the data on) that you are delivering XHTML i.e. the correct content type.

Comment: I'm reading some values from it, possibly changing some data before passing it on. I don't really want to use regex for this as it's not the right tool for the job.

Comment: @TomB the correct way would be to use xslt and identity templates, there's a good article here on that subject -> http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-tipxsltidentitytpl/  (that said, CD001's answer would probably suffice as a workaround)

Comment: I'd rather not alter the original document if I can help it, xslt feels like overkill for what I'm doing. Perhaps a better way around would be to force it to not collapse anything so everything becomes <foo></foo>. Since there are only a few tags which need to be closed in HTML (img, hr, br, meta come to mind) this could be very easily dealt with using a simple string replace on the final output.

Comment: @TomB, I hear ya. Tbh. I don't think using xslt is that arduous, you only need to write the xsl identity templates once, and apply it on output to your xml just like you would apply whatever string parsing function you're about to write. The examples on the PHP site are pretty straightforward -> http://www.php.net/manual/en/xsl.examples.php